# CSS Link Problems

Tags: css

I'm having a bit of difficulty adding some CSS to a link. I'm using a CMS that automatically generates menus in an unordered list. However, where you're on a given page, it applies class="active" the the li and not to the link itself. This works fine for adding a background to the link, but I'm trying to change the link color.

```
<li class="active">
<a href="#">Link</a>
</li>
```

I'm having difficulty coming up with the CSS to say "If a link is in an `li` with `class="active"` then make the link text color x."

How might I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the path is

```
li.active a { color: .... }
```

The [MDC CSS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference) has good examples for the various types of selectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
li.active a {color:whatever}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a
{
    color: black;
}
a.active
{
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: won't work either. He want's only the link within the li that has a class as 'active'. Your first would change all a tags. The second would look for a tags that have class="active" on them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.active a {color: red;}
```

Comment: This is incorrect - the full stop should move before the class name

Comment: I made a mistake, corrected it in 5 sec and with that time I have 2 people correcting me already =)

Comment: that's Stack Overflow for ya :) I would upvote to even out the unfair -2 but I'm out of votes for today.